# Trying to get Twitter Oauth to work in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, twitter-oauth, winjs

I am using Microsoft's authentication sample found here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122
I have not modified anything, just put in my "Consumer Secret" and "Consumer Key" all I get is "Cannot connect to the service." Other code examples give me 401 errors. Any ideas?

Comment: not having an issue here with that sample. If I have an error in the key/secret, I get 401, so it does seem like you're not getting to the service itself.  Does the behavior persist?

Comment: Yep, still haven't been able to figure it out. I'll try creating a new twitter account and generating a new key/secret.

Comment: It works now.. same consumer key / consumer secret, same example, it just work now.

Comment: what to put in callback url??

Answer (score 1):

It takes time for the Twitter servers to globally register a Ouath key across all their servers.

Comment: That's what I'm realizing now and it is extremely frustrating. In two days I have yet to even successfully post a tweet from my app. By far the worst experience I have had with any API.

Answer (score 0):

It works now.. same consumer key / consumer secret, same example, it just work now.